# javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)) throws instantiation exception while reading byte array image data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-11, java-io, javax.imageio

```
public static void createImage2() {
        try {
            BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("input.jpg"));
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", bos );
            byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            BufferedImage bImage2 = ImageIO.read(bis);
            ImageIO.write(bImage2, "jpg", new File("output.jpg") );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("image created");
    }
```

The method `ImageIO.read(bis)` throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider com.aware.j2k.imageio.J2KImageReaderSpi could not be instantiated
```

Comment: Are you saying that you read the same image *twice* (why?) and get the exception only on the *second* attempt? The quick-fix for this problem is obviously to just remove the JPEG2000 plugin, but I assume you have it installed for a reason? Is this a web application/WAR deployment of any kind?

Comment: Instead of directly use `ImageIO.read` I would first call `ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpeg")` and ignore the J2KImageReader in the iterator. Use the standard reader from Java which should be `com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader` and the process the file using `reader.setInput()` and `reader.read(..)`.

Comment: @Robert The `J2KImageReader` wouldn't be in the iterator if it worked... But it will still fail with the same exception, as the service loader expects to find the JPEG 2000 provider.

Comment: @Herald K Yes this is web app/WAR deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you application throw exception with message of SPI - java.util.ServiceLoader don't find library, for add library you must just choose and add dependency f.e. `group: com.twelvemonkeys.imageio` or another implementation

For reading image to `BufferedImage` i recommend use

```java
ImageIO.read(new MemoryCacheImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes())))
```

if you need create new image i recommend use

```java
ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(source).createBufferedImage(width, height)
```

**ATTENTION**
a lot of function for working with image use disk storage for cache or tmp by default

Comment: Above solutions are not working for me. So, I found a work around as below
```byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(image);
try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
            stream.write(data);
 }```